# Multiple Social Logins in application

Tags: android, ios, security, passport.js

I'm currently struggling with finding a solution that will give me the ability to allow my clients in my application to login from:

1. Facebook
2. Google+
3. Instagram
4. Twitter
5. Maybe more on the way

Now all i want is to allow the app connect to each of these api's **BUT** the problem is ANSE or AndroidSocialLogins apis are good but they are for Android as far as I can tell...

I saw Passport.js library which looks great and i wanted to know, when requesting(GET Method) a register/login to my Node.js that runs the Passport.js library does a HTML window opens up in my Application or it's just a request to the Passport.js api to be handled and i get only the response.

The reason that I'm asking this is because when sending to my server(Node.js) information such as Username & Password I need to consider sending it Encrypted with AES/DES or even SSL...

The issue is that I don't want to get into that and just find a nice and neet solution to handle multiple social logins without writing each api code to be handled for iOS + Android....

Thank you

Comment: Even though you are looking for a one-stop solution, for iOS my advice would be to implement them individually with each service's SDK. I've never implemented Instagram, but Facebook, Google, and Twitter are all easy to get up and running.

Comment: Yeah but still.. the fact that you need to add each api, learn how to use and maintain it by calling each api but deciding on how the user logged in is not very fun :)

Comment: I hear you! But it's better than going w/ a third party and relying on them to keep everything up to date all the time.